# Number in brackets appended to Apple TV Bonjour name

Tags: network, appletv, bonjour

I recently set up a 3rd-generation Apple TV in my living room. I have noticed that on my OS X 10.10 MacBook Pro an iPad and two iPhones (all iOS 7), the usual name of "Living Room Apple TV" appears with a "(2)" appended at the end.

After reading suggestions elsewhere, I have assigned a fixed IP address for the Apple TV and restarted the router in charge of DHCP assignments for the network. The issue persists if I change the name of the Apple TV.

Attached is anything relevant to the Apple TV in Bonjour Browser:
[image: bonjour browser screenshot]

Comment: Do you have more than one Apple TV with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to fix this issue is to add a simple space to the end of the name of the Apple TV. Restart the device and it will now show up without the bracketted number appended. My guess is that the Space acts like a wild card in the Bonjour Log and won't treat each instance of the apple TV as another instant of the last.